# how to get value from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query

```
select  sub1_s, 
        IIf(([sub1_s]<15)," /math","") AS sub1_end
```

And the following table (subject_minmum)

```
english_m   |     math_m   |  scince_m  |
12          |        15    |     10     |
```

I changed the select command to get the value 15 like this

```
select  sub1_s, 
        IIf(([sub1_s]<(select math_m from subject_minmum))," /math","") AS sub1_end
```

It works okay, but when replace many fields, I get this error message

> Too many fields defined

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "when replace many fields?"

Comment: i have many fields (sub1_s and sub2_s .and so ...........

Answer (score -1):

Google is your friend. [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198504/EN-US/)

Compact the database. On the Tools menu, point to Database Utilities, and then click Compact and Repair Database

Comment: i ask about another way to get the value